# Why did hearing impaired girl keep carrying a broken hearing aid?

Tags: plot-explanation, a-quiet-place

In "A Quiet Place" we see family hunted by monsters attracted by faintest sound. One member of the family is hearing impaired. Father keeps trying to create a working hearing aid, but is obviously failing as she still hears nothing.

Why does she carry the device anyway? Beside being inconvenient (my guess without having any experience with such devices), it is conceivable that it may:

- make sound itself,
- cause other devices to make a sound by feedback loop,
- fall off and make a sound

Wouldn't it be reasonable to take it of and disassemble after verifying it doesn't help?

Comment: You're assuming that it was _completely_ non-functional.  It may be that the hearing aid worked well enough for her to hear sound, but not well enough to understand voices, for example.

Answer (score 1):

If you're hearing impaired it can actually be hard to tell if you're making noise or not. In the movie, you have to survive by being as silent as possible so it would make sense that you would want a working hearing aid to tell if you are making any noise.

Comment: Here is an article about deaf children being unaware they are making noise https://www.dailymail.co.uk/news/article-6394001/Teacher-deaf-explain-graders-people-hear-farts.html

Comment: Ok, this part is obvious to me. But hearing aid that is not working doesn't help with this

Comment: I haven't actually seen the movie... but presumably they were trying to fix it so she could hear.

Comment: They were, but on a workbench, not on her ear

Comment: It's been a while since I'd last seen it @Mateusz, but if I recall correctly the dad insisted she wear it, and she wasn't too happy about it either. I'm a nitpicky person and this would definitely have been a question for myself if it hadn't been cleared up then. :)

Comment: This doesnt answer the question that he asked in the slightest. He did not ask why the father was working to build a hearing aid but rather why she kept carrying around a **broken** one.